# How to run dotnet restore using dotnet sdk linux docker image and mounted volume from Windows 10?

Tags: docker, build, .net-core, docker-for-windows, dotnet-sdk

I'm setting up a very simple build of a .NET Standard project using latest microsoft/dotnet sdk image (`microsoft/dotnet:2.2.104-sdk-alpine3.8`).

This is for a migration of existing code and existing build infrastructure into a new repository and build infrastructure (GitLab (not really important here)).

The new build infrastructure is of course leveraging Docker. But I also need to be able to build on my local Windows 10 using Docker (need this to prove that the SW can be built also without GitLab, without being dependent on a certain build computer).

What I have tried is to simply mount my project folder to the docker image and then run `dotnet restore`. I'm doing it interactively to understand what is going on:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume c:\projects\test-project`:/project microsoft/dotnet:2.2.104-sdk-alpine3.8
```

And then inside the container:

```
cd project
dotnet restore TestProject.sln
```

My solution is very basic. Looks like this:

```
test-project/
  src/
    ClassLibrary1/
      ClassLibrary1.csproj
  TestProject.sln
```

where `ClassLibrary1.csproj` looks like this (just referencing json.net):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

That's it.

I'm using:

- Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1709
- Docker Desktop Community Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)

The expected result is that the dotnet restore should work without issues.

The actual result is surprising to me:

```
/project # dotnet restore TestProject.sln
  Restoring packages for /project/src/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.csproj...
  Installing Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1.
  Generating MSBuild file /project/src/ClassLibrary1/obj/ClassLibrary1.csproj.nuget.g.props.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/project/src/ClassLibrary1/obj/8a35f086-c8be-4d31-93df-14c254b9be6c.tmp' is denied. [/project/TestProject.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/project/TestProject.sln]
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working as I expect it to? Am I not supposed to be able to make a restore on my mounted volume like this?

**Note:** If I run the same dotnet restore command directly from my Windows 10 computer everything works as expected.

---

**UPDATE**

The issue only appears when running the Linux container in Docker using "Windows Container mode (experimental features enabled)". Confusing to me is that I can still create and write to new files, append to existing files, etc. in the mounted folder from within the container. How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because the security context running the container isn't allowed to write into your project folder. That's not *you*, it's the user used to run docker!

Great explanation: https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/ (there's a section about Windows at the end of the article).

You can try this:

Click "Reset credentials" at the bottom of `Docker Settings` / `Shared Drives` in Docker. You will be asked for your user & password.  This will be the user used to access your files!

Comment: After some further investigations the solution seem to be simple. But I'm still not sure whether the behavior is as expected.
Anyhow. I was running Docker in "Windows Container mode". Changing it to "Linux Container mode" solves the issue (and Docker asks for my credentials if I have not yet entered them).
Still confusing to me is that I _can_ write to files in the /project folder from within the docker container, even when running the linux container in "Windows container mode". I would expect also that to fail, but it doesn't.
I will update may question with this additional info.